# phpDocumentor: RuntimeException Too many arguments

Tags: php, phpdoc

As the title says, I get an error when trying to run phpdoc. 
It works fine when I give it a directory and target:

```
phpdoc -d /mycode  -t /mydocsdir
```

Adding any other switches, like:

```
phpdoc -d /mycodedir  -t /mydocsdir  -ti 'mytitle' -o HTML:frames:l0l33t
```

throws the RuntimeException.
OSX 10.8
PHP 5.6.15 (cli)
phpDocumentor version v2.8.5

Shouldn't I be able to use the options available per the phpDocs documentation?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but I arrived here searching for how to solve the error, and I finally I got it.

I was getting the same error with running the following:

`phpdoc run -d ./* -t doc/`

But with only the dot, it is working fine for me:

`phpdoc run -d . -t doc/`

EDIT: leaving the slash also works for me:

`phpdoc run -d ./ -t doc/`

Seems that the problem is with `*`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it misses the point.  The question is about adding options in addition to the input/output directories. (sorry for responding months later...just trying to get some rep points to I can comment on answers elsewhere on SO!).